# Redirect to https conditional

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect my users to https if doesn't have "mob" suffix.

**Example:**

If url = http://example.com/(anything)/mob then **don't redirect to https**

If url = http://example.com/(anything) **redirect to https**

If url = http://example.com **redirect to https**

I tried following code but didn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)/mob$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule with `THE_REQUEST` variable:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/mob[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure to test in a new browser or clear browser cache to avoid old cache.

Suggest you to keep this rule as your top rule.